Issue with bootstrap confidence and prediction intervals of mixed effects model predictions
Recently I have asked a question on how to generate meaningful bootstrap confidence and prediction intervals for mixed effect models predictions in R using bootMer
for 1) data seen in model fit and 2) new data (i.e. not seen in model fit). I followed the approach suggested in the answer, by training a simple mixed effects model on the sleepstudy dataset with fixed effect on Days and random effect on Subject. Here is a reproducible R code, where I compute confidence and prediction intervals for a subject in the data as well as for a new subject (note: all bootMer calls are seeded).
# Load necessary libraries
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)

# Load the sleepstudy dataset
data("sleepstudy")

# Fit the mixed effect model
mem <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy)

# Define the subject for the plots
subject <- 337

# Seen subject
seen_data <- sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject == subject, ]

# New subject
new_data <- data.frame(Days = seq(min(sleepstudy$Days), max(sleepstudy$Days), length.out = 10),
                       Subject = factor(rep("999", 10)))

# Define prediction functions for bootstrapping
predfn <- function(.) { predict(., newdata = seen_data, re.form = NULL) }
cifn <- function(.) { predict(., newdata = seen_data, re.form = NA) }
sfun <- function(.) { simulate(., newdata = new_data, re.form = NA, allow.new.levels = TRUE)[[1]] }
cifn_new <- function(.) { predict(., newdata = new_data, re.form = NA) }

# Perform bootstrapping for seen subject
boot_pred <- bootMer(mem, FUN = predfn, nsim = 500, re.form = NULL, type = "parametric", seed = 2804)
boot_ci <- bootMer(mem, FUN = cifn, nsim = 500, re.form = NA, type = "parametric", seed = 2804)

# Perform bootstrapping for new subject
boot_pred_new <- bootMer(mem, FUN = sfun, nsim = 500, re.form = NA, type = "parametric", seed = 2804)
boot_ci_new <- bootMer(mem, FUN = cifn_new, nsim = 500, re.form = NA, type = "parametric", seed = 2804)

# Helper function to calculate confidence and prediction intervals
calc_intervals <- function(boot_obj, level = 0.95) {
  alpha <- 1 - level
  lower <- apply(boot_obj$t, 2, quantile, probs = alpha / 2)
  upper <- apply(boot_obj$t, 2, quantile, probs = 1 - alpha / 2)
  list(lower = lower, upper = upper)
}

# Calculate intervals
ci_seen <- calc_intervals(boot_ci)
pi_seen <- calc_intervals(boot_pred)
ci_new <- calc_intervals(boot_ci_new)
pi_new <- calc_intervals(boot_pred_new)

# Predictions
predictions_seen <- predict(mem, newdata = seen_data, re.form = NULL)
predictions_new <- predict(mem, newdata = new_data, re.form = NA, allow.new.levels = TRUE)

# Plotting
plot_intervals <- function(days, predictions, ci, pi, title) {
  data_plot <- data.frame(Days = days, 
                          Prediction = predictions, 
                          CI_Lower = ci$lower, 
                          CI_Upper = ci$upper, 
                          PI_Lower = pi$lower, 
                          PI_Upper = pi$upper)
  
  ggplot(data_plot, aes(x = Days)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = Prediction, color = "Prediction")) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = CI_Lower, ymax = CI_Upper, fill = "Confidence Interval"), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = PI_Lower, ymax = PI_Upper, fill = "Prediction Interval"), alpha = 0.1) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("Prediction" = "blue")) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("Confidence Interval" = "green", "Prediction Interval" = "red")) +
    labs(title = title, y = "Reaction Time", x = "Days") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
}

# Create plots
plot_seen_ci <- plot_intervals(seen_data$Days, predictions_seen, ci_seen, pi_seen, 
                               "Seen Subject - Confidence and Prediction Intervals")
plot_new_ci <- plot_intervals(new_data$Days, predictions_new, ci_new, pi_new, 
                              "New Subject - Confidence and Prediction Intervals")

# Print plots
print(plot_seen_ci)
print(plot_new_ci)

As you can see below, the plot for a new subject looks fine (at least qualitatively).

In the case of a subject seen in training data instead (see plot below), the confidence interval is shifted with respect to model prediction and the prediction interval. Please note that cifn is exactly the same as cifn_new and also that boot_ci is exactly the same as boot_ci_new (as suggested in the answer to my previous question).
This to me is problematic, because the confidence band for a seen subject (with both boot_ci_new and cifn_new having re.form=NA) is, in general, not centered on the corresponding model predictions (where re.form=NULL, since random effects that have been learned during model fit are rightfully included).
Question: Does it make sense at all to compute confidence intervals of mixed effects model predictions with bootstrapping for data seen in model fit? If yes, how can I have confidence intervals that are correctly centered around model predictions, like the corresponding prediction intervals? Is anything wrong in the choice of the arguments of the functions in the script?


Since this is a programming question, it would be better suited on StackOverflow.
However, I found out the issue:

In lines l.22, l.23 and l.29, re.form = NA should be re.form = NULL
In line l.22, the prediction interval should use the simulate function instead of predict.

Updating the code seems to solve the shift:

Now both confidence interval and prediction interval are centered around the same line.

Code:
# Load necessary libraries
library("lme4")
library("ggplot2")

# Load the sleepstudy dataset
data("sleepstudy")

# Fit the mixed effect model
mem <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy)

# Define the subject for the plots
subject <- 337

# Seen subject
seen_data <- sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject == subject, ]

# New subject
new_data <- data.frame(Days = seq(min(sleepstudy$Days), max(sleepstudy$Days), length.out = 10),
                       Subject = factor(rep("999", 10)))

# Define prediction functions for bootstrapping
predfn <- function(.) { simulate(., newdata = seen_data, re.form = NULL, allow.new.levels = FALSE)[[1]] }
cifn <- function(.) { predict(., newdata = seen_data, re.form = NULL) }
sfun <- function(.) { simulate(., newdata = new_data, re.form = NA, allow.new.levels = TRUE)[[1]] }
cifn_new <- function(.) { predict(., newdata = new_data, re.form = NA) }

# Perform bootstrapping for seen subject
boot_pred <- bootMer(mem, FUN = predfn, nsim = 500, re.form = NULL, type = "parametric", seed = 2804)
boot_ci <- bootMer(mem, FUN = cifn, nsim = 500, re.form = NULL, type = "parametric", seed = 2804)

# Perform bootstrapping for new subject
boot_pred_new <- bootMer(mem, FUN = sfun, nsim = 500, re.form = NA, type = "parametric", seed = 2804)
boot_ci_new <- bootMer(mem, FUN = cifn_new, nsim = 500, re.form = NA, type = "parametric", seed = 2804)

# Helper function to calculate confidence and prediction intervals
calc_intervals <- function(boot_obj, level = 0.95) {
  alpha <- 1 - level
  lower <- apply(boot_obj$t, 2, quantile, probs = alpha / 2)
  upper <- apply(boot_obj$t, 2, quantile, probs = 1 - alpha / 2)
  list(lower = lower, upper = upper)
}

# Calculate intervals
ci_seen <- calc_intervals(boot_ci)
pi_seen <- calc_intervals(boot_pred)
ci_new <- calc_intervals(boot_ci_new)
pi_new <- calc_intervals(boot_pred_new)

# Predictions
predictions_seen <- predict(mem, newdata = seen_data, re.form = NULL)
predictions_new <- predict(mem, newdata = new_data, re.form = NA, allow.new.levels = TRUE)

# Plotting
plot_intervals <- function(days, predictions, ci, pi, title) {
  data_plot <- data.frame(Days = days, 
                          Prediction = predictions, 
                          CI_Lower = ci$lower, 
                      CI_Upper = ci$upper, 
                          PI_Lower = pi$lower, 
                      PI_Upper = pi$upper)
  
  ggplot(data_plot, aes(x = Days)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = Prediction, color = "Prediction")) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = CI_Lower, ymax = CI_Upper, fill = "Confidence Interval"), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = PI_Lower, ymax = PI_Upper, fill = "Prediction Interval"), alpha = 0.1) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("Prediction" = "blue")) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("Confidence Interval" = "green", "Prediction Interval" = "red")) +
    labs(title = title, y = "Reaction Time", x = "Days") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
}

# Create plots
plot_seen_ci <- plot_intervals(seen_data$Days, predictions_seen, ci_seen, pi_seen, 
                           "Seen Subject - Confidence and Prediction Intervals")
plot_new_ci <- plot_intervals(new_data$Days, predictions_new, ci_new, pi_new, 
                              "New Subject - Confidence and Prediction Intervals")

# Print plots
print(plot_seen_ci)
print(plot_new_ci)


Thank you for your answer, Frans. I am not sure I can follow the reasoning though: what would be the point to use a mixed effects model at all if, when we predict and (estimate model uncertainty) on input data the model has seen during fit, we average over the within Subject variability that the model has learned in the random effect contribution? This, I believe, is the consequence of setting re.form=NA where you suggested. With the code you provided, if you predict for any Subject in the training data, you will always get the same predictions, CI and PI regardless of the chosen Subject.

@Marco You're right, the bug was in the same part of the code, but the fix should have been the other way around. I have updated the answer. Is this what you need?

If @FransRodenburg's post answered your question, you should consider leaving an upvote and accepting it by clicking the tick symbol alongside the answer.

@FransRodenburg Thank you, I have accepted the answer
